# Can't add a textfield in AlertController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

```
var textFD = UITextField.init()
var tempStr : String!
var datax = [Tasks]()
var tempArr = [NSManagedObject]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Add", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action:#selector(myTableViewController.addFunc))
    print("Hello")
     fetchData()
}
 func addFunc(){
    let alertO = UIAlertController.init(title: "Add", message: "Add what you want", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let saveAct=UIAlertAction.init(title: "Save", style: .default, handler:saveHandler)
    let cancelAct=UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertO.addAction(saveAct)
    alertO.addAction(cancelAct)
    alertO.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textFD) in

        textFD.placeholder="Hey therer"

        print("textfd text1 is \n\n\n" ,textFD.text!)
        self.tempStr=textFD.text!
    })
    print("textfd text2 is \n\n\n",textFD.text! )
    self.present(alertO, animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.tempStr=textFD.text!

}
func saveHandler(alert:UIAlertAction){
    print("textfd text3 is \n\n\n",textFD.text! )
    print("Value of tempStr \n\n ",tempStr)
    let taskX = Tasks(context: context)
    taskX.mydata = tempStr
    appDelegate.saveContext()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print("Value of tempStr \n\n ",tempStr)

}
```

When i click on button addFunc will call for alert and from an textfield over alert controller , later the text of textfield is stored in a string .

Alertcontroller, textfield over alert and placeholder of textfield is appear but when i trying to store textfield text into a string ( tempStr )
it can't stored !

Comment: In viewDidLoad first alloc string variable.
self.tempStr=""

Answer (score 0):

try this

**EDIT**

```
func addFunc(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "MESSAGE".localized, message: "ENTER_YOUR_MESSAGE".localized, preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addTextField { (textField) in
                // textField.placeholder = "Enter your message".localized
            }

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "TITLE".localized, style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                let textField = alert.textFields![0] // Force unwrapping because we know it exists.
                //print("Text field: \(String(describing: textField?.text))")

                if (textField.text?.characters.count)! > 0
                {
                    self.tempStr = textField.text

                }
                else
                {
                    print("empty text")
                }
            }))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I tried but I can't store textFD.text! in self.tempStr @Kamlesh Shingarakhiya

Answer (score 0):

Property `textFD` of this class is not the one that shows on `alertO`, The `configurationHandler` of textField just provide a closure to help user customize textField on UIAlertController.

To get text of textField on UIAlertController, first you need use property `textFields` of UIAlertController instance to get which textFiled you want, then use `.text` to get text of this textFiled.

Answer (score 0):

```
alertO.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textFD) in

    textFD.placeholder="Hey therer"

    print("textfd text1 is \n\n\n" ,textFD.text!)
    self.tempStr=textFD.text!
})
```

textfield is initializing with no text (blank default), tempStr is storing a blank value. you will have to save string on save action.

```
      let saveAct = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Save", style: .default, handler:{
            alertAction in
            let textField = alertO.textFields![0] as UITextField
            self.tempStr = textField.text
     })
```

Comment: @Paris0 can you describe error, Because I've successfully implemented it before posting